# How can I represent this as a sum?

Tags: probability, summation

I am solving probability, and I got the need to know what this sum is:
$ \frac{1}{2} \times \frac{1}{3} + \frac{1}{2}\times \frac{2}{3} \times \frac{1}{4} + \frac{1}{2}  \times \frac{2}{3} \times \frac{3}{4} \times \frac{1}{5} + \cdots$

I tried much with no success. How can I approach such sums during an exam?

Comment: Is it $\Sigma_{k=3}^{\infty} {\frac{(k-3)!}{k!}}$?

Comment: If TheNotMe's sum is correct, you will have $\sum_{k=1} \frac{1}{(k+1)(k+2)}$. Then, you will know how to calculate this.

Comment: Are you just looking for how to write the summation formula or are you trying to find the actual value of the infinite series?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this case, it is useful to simplify somewhat. We get 
$$\frac{1}{2\cdot 3}+\frac{1}{3\cdot 4}+\frac{1}{4\cdot 5} + \frac{1}{5\cdot 6}+\cdots.$$
This is 
$$\left(\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{3}\right)+\left(\frac{1}{3}-\frac{1}{4}\right)+\left(\frac{1}{4}-\frac{1}{5}\right)+ \left(\frac{1}{5}-\frac{1}{6}\right)+\cdots.$$
Note the **telescoping** (almost everything cancels).

**Remark:** An *expression* for the sum is $\sum_{1}^{\infty} \frac{k!}{(k+2)!}$.

Telescoping is an idea that comes up moderately often, so it is worth watching out for. On exams, the most common closed from things to look out for a geometric series, the expansion of $e^x$ for some $x$, and telescoping series.